# changing the colour of output of date function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the bellow code for getting the date and time on button click.i want to get the output in a different color..what changes are needed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayDate()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">click on the button bellow.....</p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: What is needed is learning CSS (which is where the colour should come from).

Comment: hey why did you do such a rude?im a beginer to javascript..iam trying my best to study..thanks

Comment: @mangus: I'm not being rude, just truthful. If you don't learn about CSS, you'll have another basic question about layout/appearance tomorrow, without any understanding of why it works. Doing layout in JavaScript without knowing CSS is like doing surgery as a swordsman: knowing *how* to cut paired with absolutely no idea *where* to cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `object.style.color` documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp), so in your case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayDate()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">click on the button bellow.....</p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>

</body>
</html>
```